# inserting foreign language to sql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to insert a foreign language text to my sql,

i'd tried to do:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

the SQL is also define as "Server connection collation: utf8_unicode_ci" and also the columns.

what can be the problem?
thnx.

Comment: what actual problem do you face?

Answer (score 1):

I do it using Collation:utf8_bin. I think it should work

Comment: The utf_bin encoding will store strings as-they-are (e.g., german double-s will be stored as (ß)). This is the best encoding if you are handling diacritric characters from latin, cyrillic, arabic and chinese.

Comment: it does not work as well. could the problem be in the php file?